# Error in C# random addition program

Tags: c#, math, random, addition

I keep getting an error on the line that states int userIN = int.Parse(answerBox.Text); I don't see why this is happening. I'm sure it just something I'm overlooking, but I've been sitting here totally baffled.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RandomAddition
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // First Random Nummber
            int rand1;
            Random rn1 = new Random();
            rand1 = rn1.Next(500) + 100;
            number1.Text = rand1.ToString();
            //Second Random Number
            int rand2;
            rand2 = rn1.Next(500) + 100;
            number2.Text = rand2.ToString();
            // Answer
            int anw = rand1 + rand2;
            int answ = rand1 + rand2;
            // Check
            int userIN = int.Parse(answerBox.Text);
            if (answ == userIN)
            {
                feedback.Text = "Correct";
            }
            else
            {
                feedback.Text = "incorrect";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I keep getting an error" .... what does the error say?

Comment: What is the error exactly? What is the value of `answerBox.Text` and what is your `CurrentCulture`? Debug your code and tell us.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: @TacosaurusRex: Then clearly the input string wasn't in the correct format.  What was the input string?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are building a guessing game.

Your are trying to [parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx) the text that is inside `answerBox`, but since the form just loaded it is safe to assume it is empty.

Parsing an empty string to an `int` will raise an exception.

This part of the code should only be raised in response to an event such as the user pressing a button.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `//Check` section by using `int.TryParse` instead of `int.Parse`:

```
// Check
int userIN;
if(int.TryParse(answerBox.Text, out userIN))
{
    if (answ == userIN)
    {
        feedback.Text = "Correct";
    }
    else
    {
        feedback.Text = "incorrect";
    }
}
else
{
    feedback.Text = "incorrect";
}
```

This way you avoid the FormatException when your Form is still empty.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you try to parse an empty string (answerBox.Text may be empty) to an integer, you get FormatException, please make sure the textbox contains a valid value.